# How to convert this query from SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on a query to get the role assigned to each user and display it on a table. The entities are (sorry for the picture):

[image]

I am dealing with the structure of the database which provides Identity .net. The SQL query came out as follows:

```
SELECT AspNetUsers.Id, AspNetUsers.UserName, AspNetRoles.Name
FROM AspNetUsers
INNER JOIN 
(AspNetRoles INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles 
ON AspNetRoles.Id LIKE AspNetUserRoles.RoleId)
ON AspNetUsers.Id LIKE AspNetUserRoles.UserId
```

I'd like to convert that query in LINQ or someone knows any other way to obtain the user's role for display in a table?
I'm working in Asp.NET Web Forms.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried this
string query = "SELECT AspNetUsers.Id, AspNetUsers.UserName, AspNetRoles.Name FROM AspNetUsers INNER JOIN (AspNetRoles INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetRoles.Id LIKE AspNetUserRoles.RoleId) ON AspNetUsers.Id LIKE  AspNetUserRoles.UserId";
 var Users = le.AspNetUsers.SqlQuery(query).ToList<AspNetUser>();

Comment: But I can't show the role name

Comment: @MelyCastañeda that doesn't look like LINQ what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @ad-net, your answer helped me to check my foreign keys. The correct query is:

```
var result = from u in le.AspNetUsers
             select new
             {
                 Id = u.Id,
                 UserName = u.UserName,
                 Correo = u.Email,
                 Roles = u.AspNetRoles.Select(r => r.Name)
             };
```

Thanks to all for your answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try and use this tool: http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 1):

If foreign keys are set up properly, you can do this:

```
var result = from u in AspNetUsers select new 
                {
                   Id = u.Id, UserName = u. UserName,
                   Roles = u.AspNetUserRoles.Select(r=>r.Name)
                }
```

You'll have a cleaner structure like

```
          {Id, UserName, IEnumerable<string>Roles}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Users = le.AspNetUsers.Include("AspNetUserRoles").ThenInclude("AspNetRoles").ToList();
```

aspnet users can have more than one role assigned. You can use linq `Select` method to get specific properties and map it to a new object.
http://www.dotnetlearners.com/linq/linq-to-sql-writing-select-query.aspx